# Different output from DomSanitizer bypassSecurityTrustHtml on null value angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dom-sanitizer

I've just updated an application I'm working on from angular 11 to 12.
(also updated typscript from 4.0.5 to 4.3.5).
We noticed a difference in the application, when before I had an empty value I now get the text "null" in my application.

[image]

I've narrowed down where the problem occurs and it boils down to this:
(I've hardcoded the null value for demo purpose)

```
<div>
  <span [innerHTML]="null | sanitizeHtml"></span>
</div>
```

The pipe code:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(v:string):SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
  }
}
```

So the safeHtml object returned by the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` seems to have changed, or the method has changed in dealing with a null value.
Can anyone explain this behavior?

**EDIT**

A stackblitz for reproducing the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v12-ejwhmd?file=package.json

**EDIT 2**

Created a bug for angular https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43794

Comment: not reproducible with information given (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v12-ysfksi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). dom sanitizer handles null as it always did. something else in your code is converting it to a string before it reaches the pipe.

Comment: @bryan60 Well... as said, the problem showed after updating angular from 11 to 12. 
In your stackblitz you are using angular 10, so no then problem won't show. 

I will update the question with a stackblitz for reproducing.

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered in my bug issue (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43794).

**Summary**: most likely due to typesafety improvements null is no longer excpected in the method signature of the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`. Therefore null is treated a bit different then before. It will now render like a text instead of actual null.

**Workaround** would be to address possible null values yourself before passing it to the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v12-zn77kb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html